# Error #1056 when embedding a SWF with a MovieClip containing another MovieClip in Actionscript for Mobile project using Flashbuilder 4.7

Tags: actionscript, air, flash-builder

I have an Actionscript Mobile project in Flashbuilder 4.7 compiling for Android using AIR 3.4.
( AIR SDK  location: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.345990\AIRSDK )

I recently resurrected the project from AIR 3.2 and have encountered a new run-time error.
I import a MovieClip asset (truck_anm_mc) from a SWF (originally published from Flash CS3 - in AS3, but republished using Flash CS6). The "truck_anm_mc" MovieClip contains another MovieClip with the instance name "Flick".

This is how it is imported:

```
    public var _truck_anim      :MovieClip;
    [Embed(source='/assets/blue/animation004.swf#truck_anm_mc')]
    public var TruckAnim            :Class;
```

This is how it is used (I have commented out all further references to it - this is the only line of code using it, if I comment out this line the error disappears):

```
    _truck_anim = new TruckAnim() as MovieClip;
```

This is the error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property Flick on animation004_swf$915bbdce658b4869e6dc24efe65092b42084086601.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at animation004_swf$915bbdce658b4869e6dc24efe65092b42084086601()
    ...
```

Flick is on the timeline of truck_anm_mc. 
If I delete Flick from the timeline, there is no error.

The error reports that the property Flick cannot be created on a Sprite, which would make sense to me if truck_anm_mc was a Sprite - but it is a MovieClip, which should be able to append arbitrary properties.

I have tried SWFs created with and without the Automatically declare stage instances option checked.
I am not using TLF or any RSLs. It is a very simple SWF just containing a MovieClip with another MovieClip motion tweened inside it on its timeline.

The MovieClips both use the MovieClip base document class and have their classes made dynamically by Flash.  I tried making a document class for truck_anm_mc - and declaring Flick as a public var - but it did not avert the error.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the same MovieClip asset by importing it using a different method. I exported the MovieClips in a SWC file and referenced that file from the Actionscript Mobile profile. Here is a useful tutorial on the method:

http://www.codeandvisual.com/2009/how-to-import-movieclips-into-a-flash-builder-actionscript-project/